# Вопрос связан с правильностью закрытия потоков

Tags: java, потоки-данных, jdbc

Подскажите, правильно ли я закрываю `preparedStatement`. Если нет, то как правильно это сделать ? Если до закрытия этого потока программа упадёт, то поток не закроется ? И если так, то как сделать так, чтобы поток закрывался в любом случае ?
`Connection` закрывается в другом методе, который вызывает этот метод.

```
private void update(Storage storage, File file, Connection connection)throws SQLException{

        try{
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE FILE_ SET STORAGE_ID = ? WHERE FILE_ID = ?");

            preparedStatement.setLong(1, file.getStorageId());
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, file.getId());

            boolean resFile = preparedStatement.execute();
            System.out.println("Update table File " + resFile);

            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE STORAGE_ SET SIZE_STORAGE = ? WHERE STORAGE_ID = ?");

            preparedStatement.setLong(1, storage.getStorageSize());
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, storage.getId());

            boolean resStorage = preparedStatement.execute();
            System.out.println("Update table Storage " + resStorage);

            connection.commit();

            preparedStatement.close();

        }catch (SQLException e){
            connection.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно применяется 2 паттерна до 1.6 версии включительно и после 1.7 включительно с конструкцией try-with-resource:

```
       //до 1.6 включительно
        private void update(Storage storage, File file, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatementOne = null;
            PreparedStatement preparedStatementTwo = null;
            try {
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                preparedStatementOne = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE FILE_ SET STORAGE_ID = ? WHERE FILE_ID = ?");
                preparedStatementOne.setLong(1, file.getStorageId());
                preparedStatementOne.setLong(2, file.getId());
                boolean resFile = preparedStatementOne.execute();
                System.out.println("Update table File " + resFile);
                preparedStatementTwo = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE STORAGE_ SET SIZE_STORAGE = ? WHERE STORAGE_ID = ?");
                preparedStatementTwo.setLong(1, storage.getStorageSize());
                preparedStatementTwo.setLong(2, storage.getId());
                boolean resStorage = preparedStatementTwo.execute();
                System.out.println("Update table Storage " + resStorage);
                connection.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                connection.rollback();
                throw e;
            } finally {
                if (preparedStatementOne != null) {
                    preparedStatementOne.close();
                }

                if (preparedStatementTwo != null) {
                    preparedStatementTwo.close();
                }
                connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            }
        }

        //после 1.7 включительно
        private void update(Storage storage, File file, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            try (PreparedStatement preparedStatementOne = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE FILE_ SET STORAGE_ID = ? WHERE FILE_ID = ?");) {
                preparedStatementOne.setLong(1, file.getStorageId());
                preparedStatementOne.setLong(2, file.getId());
                boolean resFile = preparedStatementOne.execute();
                System.out.println("Update table File " + resFile);
                try (PreparedStatement preparedStatementTwo = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE STORAGE_ SET SIZE_STORAGE = ? WHERE STORAGE_ID = ?");) {
                    preparedStatementTwo.setLong(1, storage.getStorageSize());
                    preparedStatementTwo.setLong(2, storage.getId());
                    boolean resStorage = preparedStatementTwo.execute();
                    System.out.println("Update table Storage " + resStorage);
                }
                connection.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                connection.rollback();
                throw e;
            } finally {
                connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            }
        }
```

И не забывайте восстанавливать auto commit.

Comment: ezhov_da, спасибо за помощь ... весь смысл был в открытии только одного statement, для экономии ресурсов ... а вот проинициализировать PreparedStatement налом, я не додумался ((

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что хотите переприсваивать PreparedStatement  одной переменной? Тогда, думаю, нет гарантии, что первый PreparedStatement закроется, если ошибка произойдет уже на втором после переприсваивания. И у Вас получиться зависшее подключение. Все таки лучше контролировать каждое подключение отдельно, но это уже ИМХО.

Comment: ezhov_da, нет, я хочу сказать, что PreparedStatement один, сначала делаю один sql-запрос, получаю данные, работаю с ними, а потом этому же PreparedStatement присваиваю другой sql-запрос, работаю с данными, делаю commit и потом в блоке finally закрываю statement ... по идее ничего не будет зависать